# AJAX Request not showing any data

Tags: php, html, json, ajax, html-framework-7

I’m creating an app with Framework7 and Cordova. When I try to make an AJAX request, the codes are perfectly executed on the browser but not on the phone ( both Android and iOS ).

HTML/AJAX:

```
<template>
<div class="page no-navbar no-swipeback home-admin-page">
    <div class="page-content home-admin-page-content">
        <div id="output"></div>
        <div id="message"></div>
        <button id="loadNew">Load New User</button>
    </div>
</div>
</template>


<script>
return {
    on: {
        pageInit: function() {
            $( '#loadNew' ).click( function() {
                app.request.get('pages/get.php', function (data) {
                    $('#output').html(data);
                    console.log('Load was performed');
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

PHP:

```
$rows = "hi";

print json_encode($rows);
```

I've gone through all of the questions available, but can't figure what's the problem.

Thanks in advance.

~ Nathan.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put your get.php file somewhere online and use that full link like "http://example.com/ajax/get.php" to send  ajax request

Comment: Maybe look at http://forum.framework7.io/t/solved-app-request-problem/3916/7, towards the bottom.

Comment: I've solved the problem but forgot the get back and post it here, and yes, this one is the true answer to my problem, thank you, Danial.